# Testing a range for X in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a form where I'm taking reservations for a range of speaking events held over multiple days.  I am trying to get it to email me when one of the days in this range reaches room capacity.  I'm measuring capacity in a cell which is FALSE until it reaches capacity then goes TRUE.

My variable on the capacity test is

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("counts");
var currentValue = sheet.getRange("D2:D13").getValues();
Logger.log('currentValue = '+currentValue)
```

This returns in the log, currentValue = false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false

I have a line in my script which is supposed to trigger an email that says.

```
if (currentValue = "true")
```

I've tried all kinds of combinations in this line.  Currently as is, it emails everytime someone submits a reservation.  :)

What should my "if" syntax be so it only emails when there is a "true" somewhere in the currentValue range?

Thanks for any help you can lend me.  Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call getValues() it returns a 2D Object[][] array, so when you log currentValue, you should get something like this:

```
[[true], [true], [true], [true], [true], [true], [true], [false], [true], [false]]
```

Spreadsheet has the capability to store boolean values, thats why whenever you type in true, it converts that value to uppercase and interprets that value as a boolen. So when you retrieve that value in the script, you should treat it as a boolean.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var currentValues = sheet.getRange("D2:D13").getValues();
for (var x in currentValues) {
  var value = currentValues[x][0];

  if (value) {
    Logger.log('True value');
    // Send email, but do you want to send an email every single time this script
    // is run??
  } else if (value == false) { // You can leave this as else instead of else if
    Logger.log('false value')
  }
}
```

I am assuming you want this script to be triggered when a user submits a form. Instead of sending an email every time the script sees a "true" value, you can store the CellRange in scriptDB and send an email only if the CellRange doesn't exist in the DB.

Comment: I'm not getting a log that looks like this.  Mine looks like currentValue = false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false

Comment: This solution actually worked.  The one above I initially thought was working, but I didn't have my error notifications setup on my test sheet, newbie mistake.  Phil's solution seemed to have an error about TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. and after reading last night, there are many people that have seen this problem.  I don't understand what is undefined?

Answer (score 1):

To check for equality,  you must use the `==` operator. Using a single equals sign means you're trying to assign the value of "true" to the variable `currentValue`. To check if they're equal, use `==`.

Secondly, you will want to iterate through each of the values of `currentValue` to check if any of them are true. So to do that:

```
//currentValue is a 2D array
var nRows = currentValue.length;
for(var i=0;i<nRows;i++) {
  if (currentValue[i][0]=="true") {
    //send email
  }
}
```

Comment: This seemed to do the trick.  I would like to add comments to your code for newbys like me to understand what it's doing.  I always wish the heavy's on SOF would comment the functions so I would like to comment the code and have your correct me if I'm not understanding it.  Thanks again Phil...

Comment: I am confused by what you mean here. Would you like my code commented? or your code commented? I apologize in advance if I haven't been clear on anything!

Comment: Phil, I created an example of further documenting the solution.  I apologize for asking for more as you've been so gracious with providing a solution in the first place.  I'm just trying to give more information about what each line of code is actually doing for us newbie coders to learn from.

Comment: I must still have something wrong.  :|  When I went to deploy the solution within my production sheet, I had error notifications turned on and I get an error.  I neglected to remember to turn them on in my test environment.  :|  This is the error.  2/12/13 12:57 PM onFormSubmit TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 39) formSubmit 2/12/13 12:57 PM  Line 39 is... if (currentValue[i][0]=="true");

Comment: Are you logging currentValue inside the for loop? `Logger.log('currentValue = '+currentValue)`? Also, be sure you take a look at my comments on your answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding additional comments to the answer I received and would like to comment the code in a little more detail so that newbies like me can learn even more from the answer.  I used the code that Phil provided to me but I deployed it in the wrong position at first.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("counts");
  var currentValue = sheet.getRange("D2:D13").getValues();
  //currentValue is a 2D array (think of it like a matrix). You can get an
  //individual element from it by calling currentValue[row#][col#]
  // for example: currentValue[3][0] will give you the item in the 4th row, 1st column
  //    NOTE: arrays are zero-based, so the first item is index 0.
  //you can also obtain a row of elements
  //  var rowThree = currentValue[2];
  //  rowThree is now a 1D array. get an element by calling rowThree[col#]

  var nRows = currentValue.length;
  //currentValue.length gives you the number of elements in the first dimension
  //of the 2D array. so in this case, it gives you the number of rows.


  for(var i=0;i<nRows;i++) {  
    //creates a new variable i, defines i is initially 0.
    //for every loop while i is less than nRows, run the loop, then increment i by 1
    //so this will run the following code once for every row number.

    Logger.log('row '+i+' col[0] = '+currentValue[i][0]); //log the value in the current row

    if (currentValue[i][0]=="true") //the double equals operator checks for equality
                                    //whereas a single equals would ASSIGN the value
                                    //"true" to the array at location [i][0]
    {
      MailApp.sendEmail("dave@davelalande.com","Talks Room Capacity  Reached","A date within the next round of Talks has reached capacity, " +
                 "\nplease check the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=""#gid=1 and removed the date.");
    }
  }
}
```

Just more information about the working solution Phil provided.

I'm currently getting and error that says...

TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 38)

which refers to this line.

```
if (currentValue[i][0]=="true");
```

The only thing I'm current logging is
    Logger.log('row '+i+' col[0] = '+currentValue[i][0]);

which is outputting this...

```
row 0 col[0] = false
row 1 col[0] = false
row 2 col[0] = false
row 3 col[0] = false
row 4 col[0] = false
row 5 col[0] = false
row 6 col[0] = false
row 7 col[0] = false
row 8 col[0] = false
row 9 col[0] = false
row 10 col[0] = false
row 11 col[0] = false
```